# update a value in wordpress wp_options

Tags: options

I am trying to modify a plugin and in which i require to update a value in wp_options which has multiple values .

My `option_name` is `ws_mem_options`

and the

`option_value` has values such as in format

```
s:20:"pro_sp_email_subject";s:36:"Thank You! (instructions for access)";s:20:"mem_email_message";s:309:"Thanks %%first_name%%!

%%item_name%%

Transaction ID: %%txn_id%%
Charges today: $%%amount%%

Your order can be retrieved here:
%%sp_access_url%%
( link expires in %%sp_access_exp%% )

If you have any trouble, please feel free to contact us.

Best Regards,
Don&#039;t Just Watch TV, Participate!";s:120:"mem_coupon_codes";s:66:"CHRISTMAS-25|25%|01/01/2021
100%OFF|100%
SAVE-10|10%
dumpme|10%";s:15:"mem_default_tax";s:4:"0.0%";s:13:"mem_tax_rates";
```

how can i add more values to

```
s:120:"mem_coupon_codes";s:66:"wow-25|25%|01/01/2021
    100%OFF|100%
    now-10|10%
    dumpme|10%";
```

Comment: Is this value in full? Is it taken from DB directly or some function's output? It looks like multiple serialized values glued together.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is serialized data-- possibly multiple bits of serialized data as @Rarst noted. The [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) will serialize and unserialize automatically so all you need to do is:

```
$data = get_option('optionkey');
// $data will be unserialized into whatever data type it was originally, object, array, etc
// manipulate your data with ordinary PHP object and array techniques
update_option('optionkey',$data);
```

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to run SQL queries, you can select the `option_value` you want to change and update it with new `option_value` by running an SQL query.